# How to update custom date field on opportunity when stage field changes from one value to other?

Tags: apex, batch, field-update

I'm trying to update a custom field on opportunity '`stagechanged__c`' field (Date-datatype) when the standard stage changed from 
   Prospecting to Qualification.

how to update date on custom field "`stagechanged__c`" field when standard stage field changes.

this is my batchjob :

```
        Global class OpportunityStageChanges implements 
       Database.Batchable<sObject> {


       Global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    String query = 'Select Id,Name,Amount,(Select ID, OldValue, NewValue 
    from OpportunityFieldHistory)from Opportunity';
    System.debug(query);

      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

     } Global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,  

         List<Opportunity> 

       scope) {

         for(Opportunity opp : scope) {


        for(OpportunityFieldHistory opfh : opp.OpportunityFieldHistory) {
          system.debug(opfh.oldValue+'----'+opfh.NewValue );
        if(opfh.oldvalue == 'prospecting' && opfh.newvalue == 'Qualification'){

            //how to update the stagechanged__c custom field
        }

    }
}

}

      Global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}

     }
```

how to update the stagechanged field ?

Thanks In Advance,
Sekhar

Comment: Why do you need batch here. You just need a trigger.

Comment: yes you are right and this is for another purpose for historical data

Comment: could you please suggest trigger for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario, a Batch class is over-engineering your problem. A trigger would be ideal.

```
trigger OnOpportunityAfter on Opportunity (before update) {

    for(Id oppId : Trigger.newMap.keySet()) {
        if(Trigger.oldMap.get(oppId).StageName == 'Prospecting' && Trigger.newMap.get(oppId).StageName == 'Qualification' ) {
            Trigger.newMap.get(oppId).stagechanged__c = Date.today();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what `date` you want to use in your custom field.

Comment: i got error like variable doesnot exist stagechanged__c but have that date field on opportunity

Comment: See updated comment. Apologies.

Comment: I tried but having some confusion at logic if you don't mine i need the same requiremt in batchjob also just update the above batch as required please?